# Linearizing a delay differential equation at an equilibrium point.

Tags: stability-theory, frechet-derivative, delay-differential-equations

I am confused about the general procedure to linearize a delay differential equation (DDE) at an equilibrium point. I was given the following two examples but I do not know how to get from DDE to linearization at an equilibrium point, $\bar{x}$.

**Example 1**

> Let $$x'(t)=bx(t)[1-x(t-r)] $$ where $b,r$ are constants. The linearization is
>   \begin{align}
> x'(t)&=bx(t) & \text{ at } \bar{x}=0\\
> x'(t)&=-bx(t-r) & \text{ at } \bar{x}=1
> \end{align}

**Example 2**

> Let 
>   \begin{align}
> x'_{1}(t)&=-b_1x_1(t)+a_{11}f_1(x_1(t-r_{11}))+a_{12}f_2(x_2(t-r_{12})) \\
> x'_{2}(t)&=-b_2x_2(t)+a_{21}f_1(x_1(t-r_{21}))+a_{22}f_2(x_2(t-r_{22}))
> \end{align}
>   where all $a_{nn}$,$r_{nn}$,$b_{n}$ are constants. Assume that $f_1,f_2$ are differentiable and $f_1(0)=f_2(0)=0$, so that $(x_1,x_2)=(0,0)$ is an equilibrium. The linearization at $\bar{x}=(x_1,x_2)=(0,0)$ is
>   \begin{align}
> x'_{1}(t)&=-b_1x_1(t)+a_{11}f'_1(0)x_1(t-r_{11})+a_{12}f'_2(0)x_2(t-r_{12}) \\
> x'_{2}(t)&=-b_2x_2(t)+a_{21}f'_1(0)x_1(t-r_{21})+a_{22}f'_2(0)x_2(t-r_{22})
> \end{align}

**Notes**

I understand that the Frechet derivative at the equilibrium point is equivalent to the linearization. Put I am not clear on how to use that fact.

In the answer to this question I am looking for a technique that allows me to linearize any delay differential equation, and connects to larger theory of the Frechet derivative.

Comment: The first one is linearising about specific solutions (the equilibria) hence certain terms factor out. Using the same symbol for the original solution and the linearisation is a possible source of confusion. Write a solution as $x+\delta$ and write out the limiting equation that it satisfies.

Comment: Still confused if you could write out the equations, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Informally, if $\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t),x(t-r))$ then we have
(using $f(x_1+h_1,x_2+h_2) \approx {\partial f(x_1,x_2) \over \partial x_1} h_1 + {\partial f(x_1,x_2) \over \partial x_2} h_2 $)
\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{(x+\delta)}(t) &=& f(x(t)+\delta(t),x(t-r)+\delta(t-r)) \\
&\approx& f(x(t),x(t-r))+{\partial f(x(t),x(t-r)) \over \partial x_1} \delta(t) + {\partial f(x(t),x(t-r)) \over \partial x_2} \delta(t-r) \\
\end{eqnarray}
From which we get
$\dot{\delta}(t) = {\partial f(x(t),x(t-r)) \over \partial x_1} \delta(t) + {\partial f(x(t),x(t-r)) \over \partial x_2} \delta(t-r)$.

Substituting values, we have
$\dot{\delta}(t) =  b(1-x(t-r)) \delta(t) - b x(t) \delta(t-r)$.

Substituting $x(t) = 0$ or $x(t) = 1$ yields the desired results.

Comment: Where does this technique come from? Do you have a reference for this technique? What is $x_1$, $x_2$?

Comment: This is the hand waving approach to linearisation. I am writing $f$ as  $(x_1,x_2) \mapsto f(x_1,x_2)$. To formalise, you need more baggage. What context are you doing this in?

Comment: You used the notation $f_1'$, $f_2'$. It is unfortunate that I choose $x$ as the variable for $f$ as well.

Comment: Okay the $x_1$, $x_2$ part makes sense. Unfortunately  I can't except your answer(as is) as I am really looking for a connection to the Frechet derivative. I will clarify that in my question.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you are looking for. The derivatives above are Fréchet, of course, but if you want a more formal answer, you need to formalise the context of the problem more (what space the solutions lie, in, etc.). One way to think of it is to consider the solution as a fixed point of an operator, much like the Picard iteration for an ODE. In this case you find the Fréchet derivative of the operator. However, you need more context first.

Comment: As an aside, I am trying to help here when I have time (and sometimes when I don't), whether you or accept or not is immaterial :-).

Comment: Okay looking it up the derivative are Frechet. My problem with this answer is that i don't see how I can generalize it (e.g. What if there are multiple delays.)

Comment: You do it in the same manner. Write $\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t),x(t-r_1),x(t-r_2),...)$ and expand as above. For equilibria, this is fairly straightforward.

Comment: I did a lot of reading your answer is fully acceptable. Thank you for answering my question and having patience.

Comment: Glad to be able to help! It took me a long time to get comfortable with such things. Unfortunately formalising the linearisation is a little tedious (at least when done through the fixed point operator) and requires some 'baggage" (what space, what does a delay mean in that space, etc.) and relatively hard to find in textbooks.